# stored procedure receiving DB name to work with

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am looking to write a stored procedure which received a database name along with other parameters, and the stored procedure needs to work on the Database which it received
any thoughts please

Comment: DatabaseNames, SchemaNames, ObjectNames, FieldNames, etc ***can not*** be parameterised within a stored procedure.  The closest you could get would be `IF (@param = 'DB1') BEGIN <code for db1> END IF (@param = 'db2') BEGIN <code for db2> END`.  The only realistic way of parameterising the database of the code encapsulated within an SP is to have code that writes code and then executes it, probably using `sp_executesql @my_dynamically_built_sql_statement`.

Comment: because I am sending a datatable with that one, i better of playing with connections string dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work, as long as correct permissions are setup:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sptest
    @DB VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sqlstmt VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlstmt='SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @DB + '.dbo.YourTableName'

sp_executesql @sqlstmt

END
GO
```

As mentioned, be very careful when using dynamic SQL like this- only use with trusted sources because of the ability to wreck havoc on your DB. At a minimum, you should add some checking of the value of @DB passed in to make sure it matches a limited list of database names that it will work with.

Comment: Be **super cautious** when using dynamic SQL. If you don't know what "dynamic SQL" is, then you shouldn't be using it. @Dave, this comment is for other readers, not aimed at you :)

Comment: Agreed- should have added that caution to my answer. :)

Comment: because I am sending a datatable with that one, i better of playing with connections string dynamically